# How to redirect all request to same file in nginx?

Tags: nginx

My root directory

/web/app/src

In this directory I have 2 directories /js/ and /assets/
and one file index.html

This is what I need to achieve:

Any request to /js/ or /assets/ or /index.html just serve files from root directory
For example myapp.com/js/app.js servers app.js from /web/app/src/js/ directory
Same with requests to /assets/

But all other requests, any other uri should result in serving index.html

For example

myapp.com/bla/bla/q?param=x
Should serve index.html from web root directory

All rewrites should be internal, no http 301 redirects.

Comment: Have you considered the [`try_files`  directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sir, please try below code. :)

```
server {
   ...
   root /web/app/src;
   ...
   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Satys! Thanks for answering! It'll help much more if you could provide an explanation besides the code. Take a quick look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer